# Setting an image as a Linux console background

Tags: linux, console

I'm not asking how to set a background image in a terminal emulator like `gnome-terminal` or `lxterm`.

I'd want to know if it's possible to set a background image to a pure linux console, and if it can be done, how.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question and its answers: https://askubuntu.com/q/701874/537750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no

Long answer: no. While you could possibly write a program that hijacks the terminal, and sets each individual cell to a different background, or even set up a custom font set to display the background image (with some gaps), there is no way currently to set a background image on the linux console. The image processing would be done using the X server, and if you are running the X server, then you are no longer in the linux console, and instead using a terminal emulator (like `lxterm` and `gnome-terminal`

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible, but you'll have to patch the kernel or find a patched one for your distribution.
Patchset is called fbcondecor.

https://github.com/mjanusz/homepage/tree/master/projects/fbcondecor

Some linux distributions offer this patch for their kernel, Gentoo Linux for instance. Here you can find more information how to configure it in gentoo.
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Fbsplash